# Twitch API Include a Cleint ID with php

Tags: php

Got a couple PHP scripts that query the Twitch API for certain informations.
However Twitch made a change and from now on you have to include a Client ID or your request doesnt get through.

My scripts look like this:

```
$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" . $_GET['username'] . "/follows/channels/" . $_GET['channel'];

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

#echo $result["created_at"];
#echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s  ',strtotime($result["created_at"]));


  $followdate = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime($result["created_at"])));
  $heute = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s'));
  $diff = $followdate->diff($heute);
```

with some research i found a website tha tprovides some help with PHP and client IDs. i found this example on how to include it:

```
<?php
 $channelsApi = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/';
 $channelName = 'twitch';
 $clientId = 'axjhfp777tflhy0yjb5sftsil';
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
       'Client-ID: ' . $clientId
    ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $channelsApi . $channelName
 ));

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But im not sure how to emerge this example into mine. In the exampel there is a Channel username and im confused if i have to do the scripts for each channel since right now the scripts are accessed by more than one channel.

Scripts are requested with: URL/scripts/followageTEST.php?username=XY&channel=XY

Would apreciate any help ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [readme of Twitch API on github](https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api#readme):

> In situations where headers cannot be set, you can also specify a client ID as a querystring parameter: client_id=[CLIENT_ID]

Here is a code that should work:

```
$client_id = 'YOUR CLIENT ID';
$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" . $_GET['username'] . "/follows/channels/" . $_GET['channel'] . '?client_id=' . $client_id;

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

#echo $result["created_at"];
#echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s  ',strtotime($result["created_at"]));

$followdate = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime($result["created_at"])));
$heute = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s'));
$diff = $followdate->diff($heute);
```

--

**Edit:**
Here is how to make a request to Twitch.tv API using `file_get_contents` function:

```
$client_id = 'YOUR CLIENT ID';
$opts = array('http' =>
    array('header' => "Client-ID:" . $client_id)
];

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
(...)
```

Comment: I think i missed that part in the twitch API readme. Il give this a try. thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay its working this way. Awesome. Thank you very much! :)